# How to enumerate bound UDP / TCP sockets on Windows in C

Tags: c, windows, sockets, tcp, udp

Assuming that you do not have access to the SOCKET handlers.

Comment: Why is that assumption necessary?

Comment: It is not really necessary, but the field was mandatory and I couldn't think of anything better to fill it with :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use either GetUdpTable or GetTcpTable functions.

Example code for GetTcpTable below (from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366026%28VS.85%29.aspx)

```
// Need to link with Iphlpapi.lib and Ws2_32.lib
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <iphlpapi.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "iphlpapi.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

#define MALLOC(x) HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, (x))
#define FREE(x) HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, (x))

/* Note: could also use malloc() and free() */

int main()
{

    // Declare and initialize variables
    PMIB_TCPTABLE pTcpTable;
    DWORD dwSize = 0;
    DWORD dwRetVal = 0;

    char szLocalAddr[128];
    char szRemoteAddr[128];

    struct in_addr IpAddr;

    int i;

    pTcpTable = (MIB_TCPTABLE *) MALLOC(sizeof (MIB_TCPTABLE));
    if (pTcpTable == NULL) {
        printf("Error allocating memory\n");
        return 1;
    }

    dwSize = sizeof (MIB_TCPTABLE);
// Make an initial call to GetTcpTable to
// get the necessary size into the dwSize variable
    if ((dwRetVal = GetTcpTable(pTcpTable, &dwSize, TRUE)) ==
        ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER) {
        FREE(pTcpTable);
        pTcpTable = (MIB_TCPTABLE *) MALLOC(dwSize);
        if (pTcpTable == NULL) {
            printf("Error allocating memory\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }
// Make a second call to GetTcpTable to get
// the actual data we require
    if ((dwRetVal = GetTcpTable(pTcpTable, &dwSize, TRUE)) == NO_ERROR) {
        printf("\tNumber of entries: %d\n", (int) pTcpTable->dwNumEntries);
        for (i = 0; i < (int) pTcpTable->dwNumEntries; i++) {
            IpAddr.S_un.S_addr = (u_long) pTcpTable->table[i].dwLocalAddr;
            strcpy_s(szLocalAddr, sizeof (szLocalAddr), inet_ntoa(IpAddr));
            IpAddr.S_un.S_addr = (u_long) pTcpTable->table[i].dwRemoteAddr;
            strcpy_s(szRemoteAddr, sizeof (szRemoteAddr), inet_ntoa(IpAddr));

            printf("\n\tTCP[%d] State: %ld - ", i,
                   pTcpTable->table[i].dwState);
            switch (pTcpTable->table[i].dwState) {
            case MIB_TCP_STATE_CLOSED:
                printf("CLOSED\n");
                break;
            case MIB_TCP_STATE_LISTEN:
                printf("LISTEN\n");
                break;
            case MIB_TCP_STATE_SYN_SENT:
                printf("SYN-SENT\n");
                break;
            case MIB_TCP_STATE_SYN_RCVD:
                printf("SYN-RECEIVED\n");
                break;
            case MIB_TCP_STATE_ESTAB:
                printf("ESTABLISHED\n");
                break;
            case MIB_TCP_STATE_FIN_WAIT1:
                printf("FIN-WAIT-1\n");
                break;
            case MIB_TCP_STATE_FIN_WAIT2:
                printf("FIN-WAIT-2 \n");
                break;
            case MIB_TCP_STATE_CLOSE_WAIT:
                printf("CLOSE-WAIT\n");
                break;
            case MIB_TCP_STATE_CLOSING:
                printf("CLOSING\n");
                break;
            case MIB_TCP_STATE_LAST_ACK:
                printf("LAST-ACK\n");
                break;
            case MIB_TCP_STATE_TIME_WAIT:
                printf("TIME-WAIT\n");
                break;
            case MIB_TCP_STATE_DELETE_TCB:
                printf("DELETE-TCB\n");
                break;
            default:
                printf("UNKNOWN dwState value\n");
                break;
            }
            printf("\tTCP[%d] Local Addr: %s\n", i, szLocalAddr);
            printf("\tTCP[%d] Local Port: %d \n", i,
                   ntohs((u_short)pTcpTable->table[i].dwLocalPort));
            printf("\tTCP[%d] Remote Addr: %s\n", i, szRemoteAddr);
            printf("\tTCP[%d] Remote Port: %d\n", i,
                   ntohs((u_short)pTcpTable->table[i].dwRemotePort));
        }
    } else {
        printf("\tGetTcpTable failed with %d\n", dwRetVal);
        FREE(pTcpTable);
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;    
}
```